# bootstrap 3 - removing XL & L fixed width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Long time lurker, first time asker! I'm unable to find what I want after a few nights of searching.

I'm looking for very standard bootstrap behavior.

1. Greater than/equal to 760px width resolution, I want fixed width.
2. Below 760px width resolution, I want the two lists to stack and take 100% width.

The problem is that above 1200px there is a different fixed width. I tried to fix this by making setting the .container class a fixed width, but then the sub 760px is also fixed --- no longer fluid. I've also tried using media queries.

Here's the code I'm working on: http://travelprobiotics.com/

Any suggestions?

thank you,
Evan Jerkunica

Answer (score 1):

If you are hosting bootstrap yourself, you can't go wrong using bootstraps customization tool found here.http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Look under the 'Media Queries Breakpoint' section and changed the screen-sm to 760px. (it is already defaulted to 768px so if you're OK giving away the 8 pixels, skip this step and use the code snippet below by itself.)

After that, add this snippet below in your own stylesheet, set the container to whatever width you want to be 'fixed'

```
@media screen and (min-width:760px) {
    .container {
        width: 960px !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also recommend using bootstrap's handy 12 column grid system to divide your page section. It will save you a ton of time writing custom styles. http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Hey Sean, thank you very much - your code worked perfectly. I'm hosting the CSS via CDN so I changed everything to 768px as you recommended.  `code`@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .container {
   width: 768px !important;
  }
 }`code` - I'm looking into the grid system as well. Thank you very much :)